# How uninstall SAP Afaria from Android device?

Tags: settings, device-administrator

I am testing the SAP Afaria in my tablet and I am no longer want use. I try uninstall the app but its locked for uninstall. In the administrator page from SAP, I didn't find how remove the enrollment.

Comment: Goto Settings>Location and Security>Device administrators
Remove the check mark from Afaria, and select Deactivate, then remove the application.

Comment: Please post that as an answer so that other users can see your problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goto Settings>Location and Security>Device administrators Remove the check mark from Afaria, and select Deactivate, then remove the application